# Merge producing unexpected results in R

Tags: r, data-management

I am trying to merge:

```
to_graph <- structure(list(Teacher = c("BS", "BS", "FA"
), Level = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BE", "AE", "ME", 
"EE"), class = "factor"), Count = c(2L, 25L, 28L)), .Names = c("Teacher", 
"Level", "Count"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
graph_avg <- structure(list(Teacher = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("BS", 
"FA"), class = "factor"), Count.Fraction = c(0.0740740740740741, 
0.925925925925926, 1)), .Names = c("Teacher", "Count.Fraction"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

with `merge(to_graph, graph_avg, by="Teacher")`, but instead of getting what I expect (3 rows), I get:

```
  Teacher Level Count Count.Fraction
1      BS    AE     2     0.07407407
2      BS    AE     2     0.92592593
3      BS    BE    25     0.07407407
4      BS    BE    25     0.92592593
5      FA    BE    28     1.00000000
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, 3 rows. I was thinking of another dataset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  `merge` is doing what it's supposed to here.

Let's look at all of the data.frames

```
graph_avg
  Teacher Count.Fraction
1      BS     0.07407407
2      BS     0.92592593
3      FA     1.00000000

to_graph
  Teacher Level Count
1      BS    AE     2
2      BS    BE    25
3      FA    BE    28

merge(to_graph, graph_avg)
  Teacher Level Count Count.Fraction
1      BS    AE     2     0.07407407
2      BS    AE     2     0.92592593
3      BS    BE    25     0.07407407
4      BS    BE    25     0.92592593
5      FA    BE    28     1.00000000
```

Now, if I'm going to merge those I've got to look and see what's common and what I'm going to get for an outcome.  Teacher, you have that in both.  But, if I try to merge on just Teacher what do I do?  There's no unique identifier for BS and it appears twice in both data.frames.  If it appeared once in one of them it would be easy to solve.  So, I go can check and say, OK, I've got a unique identifier in one data.frame, level... that would do it... and go and make something that doesn't lose any of your data.  `merge` is really handy for situations where you've got a small data.frame, say with each teacher in it once, and it has the teacher's age, or sex there.  You could merge that into your another data.frame with repeated measures on teacher and every time the teacher appears you'll also know those.  But for what you're doing it's not the right tool.

`merge` is not what you want here.  If these are really your data.frames use `cbind` instead.

```
cbind(to_graph, graph_avg$Count.Fraction)

  Teacher Level Count Count.Fraction
1      BS    AE     2     0.07407407
2      BS    BE    25     0.92592593
3      FA    BE    28     1.00000000
```

That's probably what you were looking for.

Comment: However, the downside of the `cbind()` solution is that you need to be absolutely 100% sure that the order of `to_graph$Teacher` and `graph_avg$Teacher` is identical, otherwise you'll end up connecting the wrong numbers to teachers! In this toy example it is trivial, but in a larger data set this can be easily overlooked. So, although I value your explanation of `merge()`'s approach, I would *also* expect that there's a magical combination of `merge()` parameters that does not result in the duplication of rows. So far, I cannot find it. So I guess you're right in claiming this is out of `merge

Comment: What you're asking for has no solution.  Please ask for something more specific, and that could be solved algorithmically.  You need a way to identify unique teachers in at least one data.frame, otherwise the problem isn't solvable, unless you use order... and then only if the data.frames are the same length.  This isn't an issue with the `merge` command, it's an issue of logic.  If you're telling me that I couldn't rely on order then I couldn't merge your data together at all without more information.

Comment: +1 @John, I agree with your analysis on why `merge` can't work with the data as provided.  However, I believe the OP should do the analysis differently, as I suggest in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's quite obvious that one of your datasets is derived from the other, I would suggest you don't need a merge at all, but find a way of doing the analysis in such a way that all of the data remains intact.

For example, use `ddply` in package `plyr` to derive one set from the other.  Note how this result contains all of the information you need:

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(to_graph, .(Teacher), transform, Count.Fraction=Count/sum(Count))

  Teacher Level Count Count.Fraction
1      BS    AE     2     0.07407407
2      BS    BE    25     0.92592593
3      FA    BE    28     1.00000000
```

---

To answer your question about merge.  A `merge` in R is similar to a database `join`.  To join two tables, you need to be certain that you can match the primary key in both tables.  The primary key in your case is the combination of `Teacher` and `Level`.  Since the `Level` column doesn't exist in your second `data.frame`, a `merge` is impossible.

The only way to recover this situation is to add the missing bit of the primary key back to the data.  Assuming that the data is sorted in exactly the same order, you can do this with `cbind` and then do the `merge`:

```
> merge(to_graph, cbind(graph_avg, Level=to_graph$Level))
  Teacher Level Count Count.Fraction
1      BS    AE     2     0.07407407
2      BS    BE    25     0.92592593
3      FA    BE    28     1.00000000
```

Comment: Good catch on seeing where Count.Fraction came from.  I didn't even bother assessing that.  Although, with that known then merge would work with another column copied, either Count or Level.

Comment: @John Adding `Count` as a primary key will work with the sample data, but wouldn't generalise - what happens if the Count is the same for two different Levels?